# Is it possible to detect 'end process' externally?

Tags: c++, windows

Is there some way to detect that a program was ended by windows task manager's "end process"? 
I know that its kinda impossible to do that from within the application being ended (other than to build your app as a driver and hook ZwTerminateProcess), but I wonder if there is a way to notice it from outside. 
I don't want to stop the program from terminating, just to know that it was ended by "end process" (and not by any other way).

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better way - but how about using a simple flag?

Naturally, you'd have to persist this flag somewhere outside of the process/program's memory - like the registry, database, or file system.  Essentially, when the app starts up, you set the flag to 'True' when the app shuts down through the normal means, you set the flag to 'False'.

Each time the application starts you can check the flag to see if it was not shut down correctly the previous time it was executed.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. So I can use Adam or Cory's method to detect when the program is closed, and Rob's method to tell whether it was shutdown correctly.
Now all I'm missing is a way to distinguish between "end process" and other situations of abnormal shutdown (some that i could think of are: a crash due to some uncatched exception, or simply the user pulling the plug on the computer).
All i need is some behavior that is unique to TerminateProcess. Something that my program could look for. Any little hint would help!

Answer (score 1):

Open up a handle to the process with [`OpenProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and then wait on that handle using one of the wait functions such as [`WaitForSingleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You can get the exit status of the process using [`GetExitCodeProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  If you need your program to remain responsive to user input while waiting, then make sure to wait on a separate thread (or you can periodically poll using a timeout of zero, but remember [the performance consequences of polling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/01/24/516808.aspx) -- not recommended).

When you're done, don't forget to call [`CloseHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The process object won't be fully deleted from the OS until all of its handles are closed, so you'll leak resources if you forget to call `CloseHandle`.

Note that there's no way to distinguish between a process exiting normally or being terminated forcefully.  Even if you have a convention that your program only ever exits with a status of 0 (success) or 1 (failure) normally, some other process could call `TerminateProcess(YourProcess, 1)`, and that would be indistinguishable from your ordinary failure mode.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, [ExitProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682658%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) calls the entry point of all loaded DLLs with DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, whereas [TerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) does not.  (Exiting the main function results in a call to ExitProcess, as do [most unhandled exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679327%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).)

You might also want to look into [Application Recovery and Restart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc948909%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to create a "watchdog" application (installed as a service, perhaps) that monitors WMI events for stopping a process via the `ManagementEventWatcher` class (in the `System.Management` namespace).

You could query for the death of your process on an interval or come up with some event driven way to alert of your process's demise.

[Here's sort of an example](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-csharp/71566/Trapping-process-starting-ending#1179161186770132167250e65g2000hscgooglegroupscom) (it's in C# though) that could get you started.